# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients

Tags: tensorflow

I have a simple code as following. When I tried to run it, I got the following error:

`ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(2,) dtype=int32_ref>"] and loss Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`

Any idea what I should do? Thanks.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def compute_objfunc(x1, x2, shift):

    part11 = tf.slice(x1, [shift[0]], [100-shift[0]])
    part12 = tf.zeros((shift[0],), dtype=tf.float32)
    y1 = tf.concat([part11, part12], axis=0)

    part21 = tf.slice(x2, [shift[1]], [100-shift[1]])
    part22 = tf.zeros((shift[1],), dtype=tf.float32)
    y2 = tf.concat([part21, part22], axis=0)

    return tf.reduce_sum(y1+y2)

shift = tf.Variable([1, 2], dtype=tf.int32)

x1 = tf.placeholder("float", [100,])
x2 = tf.placeholder("float", [200,])

J = compute_objfunc(x1, x2, shift)

train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(J)
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? It has multiple errors, some of them cannot be fixed without knowing what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one variable here, `shift`. Since it is an integer variable, it does not contribute any gradient. (Float variables contribute gradients. It makes sense that integer variables do not have gradients when you consider that gradients are supposed to be used to make tiny changes to the values of variables, but integer variables cannot change by a value smaller than 1. )

Should `x1` and `x2`be variables instead of placeholders?